# Flux Error: Invalid configuration: "vendorName" is not set after upgrade to Flux 9.4 and Typo3 9.5

Tags: typo3, flux, fluid, typo3-9.x

I have to make an update from Typo3 8 to Typo3 9.5 LTS. And i have some trouble with the Flux extension which causes some strange errors. I have used Flux 9.4.2 (latest) and Typo3 LTS (9.5.22). I have used Composer for the new version perhaps that causes the problem.

I have followed all the steps in this tutorial and some others instructions but all of them ends in the same error.

https://sigalambigha.home.blog/2020/04/29/how-to-migrate-fluidcontent-to-flux/

In Backend i get the following error:

[image]

And in the Frontend i get this error:

[image]

This depends on the Flux element which is on that page the Slider element. The Plug & Play configuration is disabled because of some other errors. Perhaps now i missed something in my configuration but i can't find something in the documentation to configure.

**Edit**

I have made some more tests an i think the problem is that the newest version of Flux is not really compatible with Typo3 9.5. So i changed to version 9.3.2 which is working better but has other bugs.

Answer (score 1):

##### Make sure these 3 things in your template provider extension are set correct:

1. Register the provider extension key using the `Vendor.ExtName` syntax, **not** `ext_name`. Here is an example:

```
\FluidTYPO3\Flux\Core::registerProviderExtensionKey('Nng.MyExtname', 'Page');
\FluidTYPO3\Flux\Core::registerProviderExtensionKey('Nng.MyExtname', 'Content');
```

2. Place the above code in the `ext_localconf.php` of your extension, **not** the `ext_tables.php`. You can find this hint hidden [in the documentation](https://fluidtypo3.org/documentation/templating-manual/templating/provider-extension/registration-in-php.html).
3. In older versions of FLUX you might also need to create a **ClassAliasMap** in `EXT:myextensionkey/Migrations/Code/ClassAliasMap.php`. Here is a [simple example](https://searchcode.com/file/181850163/typo3/sysext/aboutmodules/Migrations/Code/ClassAliasMap.php/).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set a small condition for the used parameter if it's null? that maybe can give an error message instead of the error in the page.

Or you should see if there's any error in the namespace

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading Flux to Typo3 9.5 then you have to register "VendorName" with your content element using Typoscript like i did below.

```
tt_content {
    mytemplate_wrapelement.20.vendorName = <vendorname>
}
```

here `mytemplate` is my template provider extension.

`Wrapelement` is the content element.

I was getting same error.